# index corrupt error while trying to index a large table

Tags: mysql, performance, index, innodb, mariadb-10.3

I am trying to index a large table, approximately 12 million rows and 33GB in size. There is currently no indexing on the table. When I am trying to index one of the columns in a table, I get the error: " Index for table 'table_name' is corrupt; try to repair it". But there are no existing indexes in this table, not sure why this error.

I am using "alter table table_name add index (DateTime);" query to add index to the table.

Can anyone please advise where could be the problem?

Its an InnoDB engine.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the statement being used to add the index.

Comment: You could try `CHECK TABLE`

Comment: Another way could be create an empty table, create index and then populate the data back in that table. It appeared that the existing table does have some probable corruption. Hope it helps